# spring cloud dataflow UI, which is configured with k8s, redirects to port 8000

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

We have spring cloud dataflow services deployed in our EKS(Elastic Kubernetes Service in AWS).

The service was deployed with [helm chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/spring-cloud-dataflow/helm) with default configuration more or less, the only thing we configured really is Spring Cloud Data Flow external database.

Now, a very strange thing is happening when trying to enter the UI:

1. enter https://<url of scdf>/dashboard
2. wait for maybe more than a min?
3. browser fails to load the UI and the url is changed to http://<url of scdf>:**8000**/dashboard/index.html
4. then removing the :8000 from address bar and trying again and it works!

We have no clue where does port 8000 is coming from?

Also, when u go to the root path https://<url of scdf> u see the different endpoints of the services, and they all show 8000 port - again, we haven't configured this port no where...

We have many other services which are exposed via k8s(registered as ingress services) and they are all working as expected

**UPDATE ADDING HELM CHART**

```
compname:
  chartName: compname/spring-cloud-dataflow
  chartPath: path
  deploymentName: spring-cloud-dataflow
  namespace: default
  productLine: productline

# Original chart values: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow/values.yaml
vault:
  enabled: true

global:
  imageRegistry: ""
  imagePullSecrets: []
  storageClass: ""

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
commonLabels: {}
kubeVersion: ""
clusterDomain: cluster.local
extraDeploy: []

server:
  image:
    registry: registery
    repository: infra
    tag: bitnami-docker-spring-cloud-dataflow-2.9.1-debian-10-r27
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    pullSecrets: []
    debug: false
  hostAliases: []
  composedTaskRunner:
    image:
      registry: registry
      repository: infra
      tag: bitnami-docker-spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner-2.9.1-debian-10.r27
  configuration:
    streamingEnabled: false
    batchEnabled: true
    accountName: default
    trustK8sCerts: false
    containerRegistries: {}
    grafanaInfo: ""
    metricsDashboard: ""
    defaultSpringApplicationJSON: true
  existingConfigmap: ""
  extraEnvVars: []
  extraEnvVarsCM: ""
  extraEnvVarsSecret: ""
  replicaCount: 1
  strategyType: RollingUpdate
  podAffinityPreset: ""
  podAntiAffinityPreset: soft
  containerPort: 8080
  nodeAffinityPreset:
    type: ""
    key: ""
    values: []
  affinity: {}
  nodeSelector: {}
  tolerations: []
  podAnnotations: {}
  priorityClassName: ""
  podSecurityContext:
    fsGroup: 1001
  containerSecurityContext:
    runAsUser: 1001
  resources:
    limits: {}
    requests: {}
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    timeoutSeconds: 1
    periodSeconds: 20
    failureThreshold: 6
    successThreshold: 1
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    timeoutSeconds: 1
    periodSeconds: 20
    failureThreshold: 6
    successThreshold: 1
  customLivenessProbe: {}
  customReadinessProbe: {}

  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 8080
    nodePort: ""
    clusterIP: ""
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    loadBalancerIP: ""
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
    annotations: {}

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    path: /
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    hostname: hostname
    annotations: {}
    tls: false
    extraHosts: []
    extraTls: []
    secrets: []
  initContainers: []
  sidecars: []
  pdb:
    create: false
    minAvailable: 1
    maxUnavailable: ""
  autoscaling:
    enabled: false
    minReplicas: ""
    maxReplicas: ""
    targetCPU: ""
    targetMemory: ""
  extraVolumes: []
  extraVolumeMounts: []
  jdwp:
    enabled: false
    port: 5005
  proxy: {}

skipper:
  enabled: false
  hostAliases: []
  image:
    registry: registry
    repository: infra
    tag: bitnami-docker-spring-cloud-skipper-2.8.1-debian-10-r26
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    pullSecrets: []
    debug: false
  configuration:
    accountName: default
    trustK8sCerts: false
  existingConfigmap: ""
  extraEnvVars: []
  extraEnvVarsCM: ""
  extraEnvVarsSecret: ""
  replicaCount: 1
  strategyType: RollingUpdate
  podAffinityPreset: ""
  podAntiAffinityPreset: soft
  nodeAffinityPreset:
    type: ""
    key: ""
    values: []
  affinity: {}
  nodeSelector: {}
  tolerations: []
  podAnnotations: {}
  priorityClassName: ""
  podSecurityContext:
    fsGroup: 1001
  containerSecurityContext:
    runAsUser: 1001
  resources:
    limits: {}
    requests: {}
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    timeoutSeconds: 1
    periodSeconds: 20
    failureThreshold: 6
    successThreshold: 1
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    timeoutSeconds: 1
    periodSeconds: 20
    failureThreshold: 6
    successThreshold: 1
  customLivenessProbe: {}
  customReadinessProbe: {}
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 80
    nodePort: ""
    clusterIP: ""
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    loadBalancerIP: ""
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
    annotations: {}
  initContainers: []
  sidecars: []
  pdb:
    create: false
    minAvailable: 1
    maxUnavailable: ""
  autoscaling:
    enabled: false
    minReplicas: ""
    maxReplicas: ""
    targetCPU: ""
    targetMemory: ""
  extraVolumes: []
  extraVolumeMounts: []
  jdwp:
    enabled: false
    port: 5005

externalSkipper:
  host: localhost
  port: 7577

deployer:
  metadata:
    annotations: {}
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 1024Mi
    requests: {}
  readinessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
  livenessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 90
  nodeSelector: ""
  tolerations: {}
  volumeMounts: {}
  volumes: {}
  environmentVariables: ""
  podSecurityContext:
    runAsUser: 1001

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: ""

rbac:
  create: true

metrics:
  enabled: true
  image:
    registry: registry
    repository: infra
    tag: bitnami-docker-prometheus-rsocket-proxy-1.3.0-debian-10-r334
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    pullSecrets: []
  resources:
    limits: {}
    requests: {}
  replicaCount: 1
  podAffinityPreset: ""
  podAntiAffinityPreset: soft
  nodeAffinityPreset:
    type: ""
    key: ""
    values: []
  affinity: {}
  nodeSelector: {}
  tolerations: []
  podAnnotations: {}
  priorityClassName: ""
  service:
    httpPort: 8080
    rsocketPort: 7001

  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    extraLabels: {}
    namespace: ""
    interval: ""
    scrapeTimeout: ""
  pdb:
    create: false
    minAvailable: 1
    maxUnavailable: ""
  autoscaling:
    enabled: false
    minReplicas: ""
    maxReplicas: ""
    targetCPU: ""
    targetMemory: ""

waitForBackends:
  enabled: true
  image:
    registry: registry
    repository: infra
    tag: bitnami-docker-kubectl-1.19.16-debian-10-r27
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    pullSecrets: []
  resources:
    limits: {}
    requests: {}

mariadb:
  enabled: false
  architecture: standalone
  auth:
    rootPassword: ""
    username: dataflow
    password: change-me
    database: dataflow
    forcePassword: false
    usePasswordFiles: false
  initdbScripts:
    create_databases.sql: |
      CREATE OR REPLACE USER 'skipper'@'%' identified by 'change-me';
      CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `skipper`;
      GRANT ALL ON skipper.* to 'skipper'@'%';
      FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

flyway:
  enabled: true

externalDatabase:
  host: host
  port: 3306
  driver: ""
  scheme: "mysql"
  password: "vault:kubernetes/productline/data/scdf#SCDF_DB_PASSWORD"
  existingPasswordSecret: "True"
  existingPasswordKey: "password"
  dataflow:
    url: ""
    database: dataflow
    username: "vault:kubernetes/productline/data/scdf#SCDF_DB_USER"
  skipper:
    url: ""
    database: skipper
    username: skipper
  hibernateDialect: ""

rabbitmq:
  enabled: false
  auth:
    username: user

externalRabbitmq:

  enabled: false
  host: localhost
  port: 5672
  username: guest
  password: guest
  vhost: ""
  existingPasswordSecret: ""

kafka:
  enabled: false
  replicaCount: 1
  offsetsTopicReplicationFactor: 1
  zookeeper:
    replicaCount: 1

externalKafka:
  enabled: false
  brokers: localhost:9092
  zkNodes: localhost:2181
```

Comment: What values have you used to install with helm?

Comment: @gohm'c added(removed only some credentials)

Answer (score 0):

![enter image description here](apiVersion: v1 kind: Pod metadata:   name: nginx spec:   containers:   - name: nginx     image: nginx:1.14.2     ports:     - containerPort: 80)

Comment: hey - I really dont understand your answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).